# Not able to run with iOS device emulator in Smartface App Studio

Tags: smartface.io

Having individual license and trying to run it with iOS device emulator.

1. Installed updated smartface-in-action in my iPhone 5
2. Connected iPhone 5 with USB
3. Selected "iOS" from profile dropdown and clicked on "Device Emulator".

But, it's saying 'Device found'... Keep calm ;)

[image]

Can any one suggest or help me to get out from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of iOS restrictions. It is not possible to make changes on an application which is downloaded from store.
Therefore, for licenced users Smartface has a solution, you can send email to support team of smartface and ask for this editable application's download link.